# Inserting values into database by looping

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a script where I'm getting information from a database and automatically importing it into a table using PHP and creating a form. In the form I'm naming the fields by whatever the data in they contain in the database. I'm having trouble in the values part of the query inserting the form values into the database because I'm not sure how to loop through and add all the input fields. How would I do this?

```
 while ($aRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($aResult)) {
        if ($aRow['correct'] == 1) {
            $tableString .= "<input name=". $qRow['questionID'] ."
                                type='radio'
                            >" .
                                $aRow['answerValue'] . "<br />";
        } else {

            $tableString .= "<input name=". $qRow['questionID'] ."
                                type='radio'
                            >" .
                                $aRow['answerValue'] . "<br />";
        } 
        $answer= [$aRow];
        $question= [$qRow];
        $student= [$username];

        // Insert data into mysql 
        //$sql="INSERT INTO $userexam(answerID, questionID, userID)VALUES('$answer', '$question', '$student')";
        //$result=mysql_query($sql);

         $query = " INSERT INTO userexam ( 
                                answerID, 
                                questionID, 
                                userID) 
                            VALUES ( '" . $_POST['/* answerID */'] . "', '" . 
                                        $_POST['/* questionID */'] . "', '" . 
                                        $_POST['/* userrole */'] . "')";
    }
```

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions. They've been deprecated for over 2 years now and they will no longer work in PHP 7+. Your code is wide open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This basicly means that it would take less than a minute for any visitor of your website to do whatever they want with your database. That includes destroying it. Considder using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead in combination with [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with radio buttons is: They are not send via $_POST if they are not checked. You need to "know" what radiobuttons exist and those who are not send with $_POST are not checked.

As for the looping:
You can give your radio buttons a "main" name in addition to your IDs:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="foo[23]">
    <input type="radio" name="foo[45]">
    <input type="submit" value="foo">
</form>
```

Take a look at the $_POST variable and you see that both radio buttons are within an array. You can use that array to iterate through all checked radio buttons.

And please start using PDO instead of mysql_  :)